# not being able to persist entity in JPA in spring 3

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa

I am not being able to persist entity in JPA, although findAll works
here.
Here is the JpaDAO

```
package aop.web.teacher.dao;

import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceException;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaCallback;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.JpaDaoSupport;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


public abstract class JpaDAO extends JpaDaoSupport {
 protected Class entityClass;

 private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(JpaDAO.class);

 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public JpaDAO() {
  ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass()
    .getGenericSuperclass();
  this.entityClass = (Class) genericSuperclass
    .getActualTypeArguments()[1];
 }

 @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
 public void persist(E entity) {
  getJpaTemplate().persist(entity);
 }

 @Transactional
 public void remove(E entity) {
  getJpaTemplate().remove(entity);
 }

 @Transactional
 public E merge(E entity) {
  return getJpaTemplate().merge(entity);
 }

 @Transactional
 public void refresh(E entity) {
  getJpaTemplate().refresh(entity);
 }

 @Transactional
 public E findById(K id) {
  return getJpaTemplate().find(entityClass, id);
 }

 @Transactional
 public E flush(E entity) {
  getJpaTemplate().flush();
  return entity;
 }

 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 @Transactional
 public List findAll() {
  Object res = getJpaTemplate().execute(new JpaCallback() {

   public Object doInJpa(EntityManager em) throws PersistenceException {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT h FROM "
      + entityClass.getName() + " h");
    return q.getResultList();
   }

  });

  return (List) res;
 }

 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 @Transactional
 public Integer removeAll() {
  return (Integer) getJpaTemplate().execute(new JpaCallback() {

   public Object doInJpa(EntityManager em) throws PersistenceException {
    Query q = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM " + entityClass.getName()
      + " h");
    return q.executeUpdate();
   }

  });
 }

}
```

Here is the TestDao class

```
package aop.web.teacher.dao;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;



import aop.web.teacher.rmodels.Teachermaster;

@Service
@Repository
public class TestDaoImpl extends JpaDAO implements TestDao {

 @Autowired
 EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

 @PersistenceContext
 private EntityManager em;

 @PostConstruct
 public void init() {
  super.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
 }

 public int saveTeacher() {
  List teacherList = findAll();
  Teachermaster m1 = teacherList.get(0);
  logger.info("Found " + m1.getId() + " and " + m1.getRace());
  m1.setRace(m1.getRace() + "::" + System.currentTimeMillis());
  logger.info("New " + m1.getId() + " and " + m1.getRace());
  persist(m1);
  return 0;
 }

}
```

Here is the spring context xml

http://pastebin.com/pKqzW9h1

Here the findAll works
but when we make a change to the attribute of the Teachermaster
then persist or merge does not seem to save the entity... 
If we flush it we get exception

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
```

Please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling a local method when invoking `persist()` from your test class. This way the proxy that would create transactions is not invoked so your call to `persist()` has no transaction.

The way to do this properly is to have the test class **not** extend the object under test but have it injected. This way the proxy will be triggered and the transaction will be created.

By the way, I must add that I find your class design a little bit beculiar. May I suggest creating a structure like the following?

DAO interface:

```
public interface FooDao {
    void persist(Foo foo);
    // ...
}
```

DAO implementation:

```
public class FooDaoImpl implements FooDao {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public void persist(Foo foo) {
        entityManager.persist(foo);
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJunit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(...)
public class FooDaoTest {
    @Autowired
    private FooDao fooDao;

    @Test
    public void testPersist() {
        // do some testing
    }
}
```

You can, if you wish, extract most of the logic in the DAO implementations into a generic superclass.

Answer (score 5):

Spring uses proxy-based AOP, therefore aspects (including transactional aspect) are not applied when methods are called from the same class.

Generally speaking

- `@Transactional` annotations should be usually placed on service methods rather than on DAO methods
- Your `saveTeacher()` looks like a service method, it would be better to place it in the separate service class and annotate as `@Transactional`
- You don't need `persist()` in `saveTeacher()` - changes made to persistent objects should be saved automatically
- Beware of dynamic proxy vs target class proxy distinction (regarding to `TestDao`) - see the links below

**See also:**

- [7.6.1 Understanding AOP proxies](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies)
- [10.5.1 Understanding the Spring Framework's declarative transaction implementation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained)